# FFMPEG is not able to find window for edge browser

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, microsoft-edge

I am trying to capture video recording for edge browser using below command

```
ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -framerate 9 -i title="About version - Profile 1 - Microsoft​ Edge' -vcodec libx264 -threads 1 -crf 35 -preset ultrafast -f hls -g 15 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 5 -r 7 -pix_fmt yuv420p -maxrate 1.7M -bufsize 2M -tune zerolatency -vf pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2 index.m3u8
```

This is how I found title for edge browser

```
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq msedge.exe" /fo list
```

This is the error I get (notice the weird character)

```
 Can't find window 'About version - Profile 1 - MicrosoftΓÇï Edge'
```

I have also verified the title with AutoIt application. This is working fine for chrome and firefox. Let me know if some is able to record the edge browser via ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

According to your issue, I tried to record video of Edge window using FFMPEG, and it works fine.

I think your issue caused by wrong command：

```
title="About version - Profile 1 - Microsoft​ Edge'
```

The leading and trailing quotes don't correspond, I reproduced your problem through it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying out. I fixed the quote but still I get the same error. Can you share the whole command that you tried which was working fine. Also were you using powershell or cmd ?

Comment: I tested the command line you provided and just changed the window title using cmd. Here is my [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9t5O.png) and [part of its result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfnar.png).